# android keep giving my app this error :addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported

Tags: android, compiler-errors, adapter

my app keep giving this error :addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

then i changed the adapter from simple to custom , because i searched for a solution.
then i made my custom adapter ,but i keep getting this error i don't know why .
how can i solve this ?

```
public class Main_activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);

    ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    ArrayList<String> listIds =  new ArrayList<String>();
    listIds.add("txtname");
    listIds.add("btnnum");
    listIds.add("txtTran");
    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,listIds);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    populateList();
}

static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = 
    new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 

private void populateList() {
    if(!list.isEmpty())
        list.clear();

    HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp1.put("txtname","test1");
    temp1.put("btnnum", "1");
    temp1.put("txtTran", "4x");

    list.add(temp1);
    HashMap<String,String> temp2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp2.put("txtname","test2");
    temp2.put("btnnum", "2");
    temp2.put("txtTran", "3.5x");

    list.add(temp2);
    HashMap<String,String> temp3 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp3.put("txtname","test3");
    temp3.put("btnnum", "3");
    temp3.put("txtTran", "3.2x");

    list.add(temp3);
    HashMap<String,String> temp4 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp4.put("txtname","test4");
    temp4.put("btnnum", "4");
    temp4.put("txtTran", "2.4x");

    list.add(temp4);

}
protected CustomAdapter mAdapter;
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    protected Context mContext;
    protected ArrayList<String> mItems;
    protected LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row_view, items); // Use a custom layout file
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("enters");
        if(convertView == null){

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view,null);
        }



      ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nametxt)).setText(list.get(position).get("txtname"));
      ((Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnnum)).setText(list.get(position).get("btnnum"));
      ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.transtxt)).setText(list.get(position).get("txtTran"));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok  , so i solved this . The problem was because i added a framelayout to my layout and forgot to put details about it i had it like this :

```
 <FramLayout android:id="@+id/f1">
```

the layout was giving the problem and i thought it was from the activity.